# Arraylist populated by copies of the last element Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a mobile version of a board game and for some reason I have an ArrayList where all elements conform to the last element whenever a new one is added and I can´t figure out why.
(i am pretty new to Android Studio)

Below are all the classes that are concerned with adding to the list:

```
public class ScoreBoard {
    private static final ScoreBoard ourInstance = new ScoreBoard();

    public static ScoreBoard getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    List<Player> Players;
    int nrOfPlayers;
    int activePlayer;

    private ScoreBoard() {
        Players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    }

    public void addPlayer(CharSequence name) {
        Player p = new Player(name);
        Players.add(p);
    }

    public void nrOfPlayers(int number)
    {
        nrOfPlayers = number;
    }

    public boolean stop()
    {
        boolean stop = false;

        if (nrOfPlayers <= Players.size())
        {
            stop = true;
        }
        return stop;
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt(nrOfPlayers);
    }

    public CharSequence GetActivePlayerName()
    {
        return Players.get(activePlayer).name;
    }
}

public class Player { 
    public CharSequence name;
    public int points;

    public Player(CharSequence name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class PlayerName extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_name);
    }

    public void addPlayer(View view)
    {
        ScoreBoard SB = ScoreBoard.getInstance();
        TextView nameText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NameText);
        TextView playerText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PlayerText);
        CharSequence name = nameText.getText();
        SB.addPlayer(name);
        playerText.setText("Player " + (SB.Players.size() + 1) + " enter your name");
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, name + " Added", duration);
        toast.show();

        if(SB.stop())
        {
            SB.StartGame();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TakeTurn.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by conform to the last element?

Comment: that all the elements become duplicates of the last added element (should have worded that better)

Comment: "Hey, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

You've used `static` and `final` while initializing. Remove them and modify your Scorecard class as follows:

```
private ScoreBoard ourInstance = new ScoreBoard();

    public ScoreBoard getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }
```

Comment: i don´t know if that would solve the problem (have to do some changes to my code to accommodate it) but if i do this, i won´t be able to use my scoreboard class as a singleton class right?

Comment: You can have a singleton class if you declare the class constructor as private. I'm not entirely sure about that though. Try it and if it works it'll be a singleton class only. Refer here: http://www.java2novice.com/java_constructor_examples/singleton/